# Storing result of an API call in cache in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I'm trying to use `Cache::remember` to fetch some data or store it in the cache if not yet set.

```
$artists = Cache::remember('artists', 60, function(\Barryvanveen\Lastfm\Lastfm $lastfm){
    return $lastfm->userTopArtists('un')->period(\Barryvanveen\Lastfm\Constants::PERIOD_WEEK)->limit(5)->get();
});
```

But I'm getting a `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError` error:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(), 0 passed in .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php on line 383 and exactly 1 expected
```

I'm doing this in a view controller, but have reduced my code above down to a reproducible error in Tinker.

This is in Laravel 6.9.0, using the default `file` cache driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working. Instead of passing the class instance in the closure function arguments, it needs to be passed using `use`:

```
function() use (\Barryvanveen\Lastfm\Lastfm $lastfm) {
```